# XSLT -Cut and Paste

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

how to do cut and paste in xslt? suppose my xml like this,

```
  <root>
    <header>
      some nodes
    </header>
    <body>
    <p>
      some text
    <link>1</link>
      <note xml:id="c5-note-0001" numbered="no">text</note>
    </p>
    <p>
      some text
      <link>2</link>
      <figure>
        <note xml:id="c5-note-0003">text</note>
      </figure>
      <note xml:id="c5-note-0002">text</note>
    </p>
    <tabular>
      <note xml:id="c5-note-0004" numbered="no">text</note>
    </tabular>
    <p>
      some text
      <link>3</link>
      <notegroup>
        <note xml:id="c5-note-0006">text</note>
      </notegroup>
      <note xml:id="c5-note-0005">text</note>
    </p>
    <p>
      some text
      <link>4</link>
      <note xml:id="c5-note-0007">text</note>
    </p>
    </body>
  </root>
```

my expected output is,

```
  <root>
    <header>
      some nodes
    </header>
    <body>
      <p>
        some text
        <link>1</link>
        <note xml:id="c5-note-0001" numbered="no">text</note>
      </p>
      <p>
        some text
        <link>2</link>
        <figure>
            <note xml:id="c5-note-0003">text</note>
        </figure>
        <notenum>1</notenum>
      </p>
      <tabular>
        <note xml:id="c5-note-0004" numbered="no">text</note>
      </tabular>
      <p>
        some text
        <link>3</link>
        <notegroup>
          <note xml:id="c5-note-0006">text</note>
        </notegroup>
        <notenum>2</notenum>
      </p>
      <p>
        some text
        <link>4</link>
        <notenum>3</notenum>
      </p>
      <newnote>
        <note xml:id="c5-note-0002">text</note>
        <note xml:id="c5-note-0005">text</note>
        <note xml:id="c5-note-0007">text</note>
      </newnote>
    </body>
  </root>
```

i need to create a new node `newnote` before the end of body tag and cut and paste the `note` node into that and need to generate a `notenum` node instead of that `note`.

i need to do this only within the `p` node. if the `note` comes under `tabular`, `figure` and `notegroup` then no need to do anything.

if `note` contains attribute like `numbered="no"` then no need to do anything.

i am using the following xslt(just to show the template match that i am using),

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
  >
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match ="figure">
      some operation
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match ="tabular">
      some operation
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match ="notegroup">
      some operation
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not seeing any `<count>` element in your expected output, even though it's allegedly (as per your description text) generated. Also, do you mean *cut and paste* or *copy and paste* regarding the `<note>` elements?

Comment: count node means `notenum` that's generated instead of `note`. i need to do cut and paste. pls see my input and expected output.

Comment: I see now; got confused about the various kinds of `<note>` elements that get or do not get moved. I've added an appropriate answer that hopefully does what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In general, it's beneficial in XSLT to imagine "cut and paste" as what it actually is, namely "copy and paste and delete the original".*

> i need to create a new node newnote before the end of body tag and cut and paste the note node into that

What you want to do is adapt the `<body>` element so it contains, after its (possibly otherwise modified) original contents, a new `<newnote>` element. Therefore, add a new template for the `<body>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
</xsl:template>
```

As mentioned before, you want to basically take over the original contents. As that original contents may still be processed by other templates, we'll use `<xsl:apply-tepmlates>` here:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

After the original contents, you want to insert the new element:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <newNote>
    </newNote>
</xsl:template>
```

Finally, in this element, you want a copy of all the described `<note>` elements, which can be achieved with an `<xsl:for-each>` loop:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <newnote>
        <xsl:for-each select="p/note[not(@numbered = 'no')]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </newnote>
</xsl:template>
```

> and need to generate a notenum node instead of that note.

This can be done with a template replacing the respective `<note>` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="p/note[not(@numbered = 'no')]">
    <notenum><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::note[parent::p][not(@numbered = 'no')]) + 1"/></notenum>
</xsl:template>
```

Insert the new `<notenum>` element instead and use the `<xsl:value-of>` command to output a computed value. The value is the number of preceding `<note>` elements that match your restrictions plus one.